# How can I find the change in trend in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, stock

```
                             open   high    low     close   volume  openclose
date                        
2020-08-04 09:15:00+05:30   227.00  229.00  226.40  226.70  157982  -0.30
2020-08-04 09:20:00+05:30   226.55  226.80  222.40  223.15  253212  -3.40
2020-08-04 09:25:00+05:30   223.00  223.15  220.15  220.15  236819  -2.85
2020-08-04 09:30:00+05:30   220.15  220.60  217.55  219.90  628153  -0.25
2020-08-04 09:35:00+05:30   219.70  221.80  218.90  221.60  260912  1.90
```

So there is a decreasing trend in the `openclose` column and suddenly there is an increasing trend, how can I determine if there is a series of decreasing trend and change in trend.

Any clues or help will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: best is to visualize the data in a plot if you are up to determining an increase or decrease in trend.

Comment: @TanmayaMeher - I am trying to algo trading with this. That is the reason.Thanks for ur time for respoding.

Answer (score 4):

You want to determine the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) (`dy / dx`) and see if it is negative or positive. If it's positive it means that there was a positive trend:

```
derivative = df['openclose'].diff() / df.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds()
df['trend'] = derivative.gt(0).map({False: -1, True: 1})
```

```
                             open    high     low   close  volume  openclose  trend
date                                                                               
2020-08-04 09:15:00+05:30  227.00  229.00  226.40  226.70  157982      -0.30     -1
2020-08-04 09:20:00+05:30  226.55  226.80  222.40  223.15  253212      -3.40     -1
2020-08-04 09:25:00+05:30  223.00  223.15  220.15  220.15  236819      -2.85      1
2020-08-04 09:30:00+05:30  220.15  220.60  217.55  219.90  628153      -0.25      1
2020-08-04 09:35:00+05:30  219.70  221.80  218.90  221.60  260912       1.90      1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Everything depends on your model**

one approach

```
df['chg'] = df['openclose'] -df['openclose'].shift(1)
df['chg']>0

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

others :

- can be cross over of some moving averages
- can be detecting outliers
- can be keeping whenever there is a decrease in negative counts
- can be using `statistics` like z-score method
- there can be `Time Series analysis` (Trend related )
- there can be `technical analysis`  and many more.
- there can be proper financial modeling methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use extreme point. Find the local maxima and minima.

- idx_ is the index where extreme point is located.
- type, 0 is minimum value. and 1 is maximum value.
- close is the price when extreme point located.

.

```
def get_max_min(df, smoothing=4, window_range=10):
    smooth_df = df['close'].rolling(window=smoothing).mean().dropna()
    local_max = argrelextrema(smooth_df.values, np.greater)[0]
    local_min = argrelextrema(smooth_df.values, np.less)[0]
    price_local_max_dt = []
    for i in local_max:
        if (i > window_range) and (i < len(df) - window_range):
            price_local_max_dt.append(df.iloc[i - window_range:i + window_range]['close'].idxmax())
    price_local_min_dt = []
    for i in local_min:
        if (i > window_range) and (i < len(df) - window_range):
            price_local_min_dt.append(df.iloc[i - window_range:i + window_range]['close'].idxmin())
    maxima = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[price_local_max_dt])
    minima = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[price_local_min_dt])

    max_min = pd.concat([maxima, minima]).sort_index()
    max_min.index.name = 'idx_'
    max_min = max_min.reset_index()
    max_min = max_min[~max_min.idx_.duplicated()]
    max_min = max_min.reset_index(drop=True)

    maxima.index.name = 'idx_'
    maxx = maxima.reset_index()
    maxx = maxx[~maxx.idx_.duplicated()]
    maxx = maxx.assign(type=[1]*len(maxx))
    maxx = maxx[['idx_', 'type', 'close']]

    minima.index.name = 'idx_'
    minn = minima.reset_index()
    minn = minn[~minn.idx_.duplicated()]
    minn = minn.assign(type=[0]*len(minn))
    minn = minn[['idx_', 'type', 'close']]

    resminMax = pd.concat([minn, maxx]).sort_values('idx_')
    resminMax = resminMax.reset_index(drop=True)
    return resminMax
```